# Laravel orderBy and groupBy with if statement

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I try to retrieve the message groups from the database and The query is not ordering the results by `created_at` flag.

The query looks like this:

```
$groups = self::
    where(function($query) use ($user_id) {
        $query->where('to_id', $user_id);
        $query->orWhere('from_id', $user_id);
    })
    ->join('users as u1', 'user_messages.to_id', 'u1.id')
    ->join('users as u2', 'user_messages.from_id', 'u2.id')
    ->select(
        'u1.nickname as u1_nickname',
        'u1.id as u1_id',
        'u2.id as u2_id',
        'u2.nickname as u2_nickname',
        'user_messages.created_at'
    )
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->groupBy(
        DB::raw(
            'if (user_messages.from_id = '.$user_id.', user_messages.to_id, user_messages.from_id)'
        )
    )
    ->get()
    ->toArray();
```

Where `$user_id` is the authenticated user.
The orderBy clause is not working as expected. The users are not grouped by the last who sent a message.

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: try `orderBy()` after `groupBy()`

Comment: Thank you but is not working.

Comment: what does `dd(groups)` gives?

Comment: Can you please add your table structure, some sample data and the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Max` to get the latest `created_at` for each message. 
The query may be like:

```
$groups = self::
where(function($query) use ($user_id) {
    $query->where('to_id', $user_id);
    $query->orWhere('from_id', $user_id);
  })
->join('users as u1', 'user_messages.to_id', 'u1.id')
->join('users as u2', 'user_messages.from_id', 'u2.id')
->selectRaw(
    'u1.nickname as u1_nickname,
     u1.id as u1_id,
     u2.id as u2_id,
     u2.nickname as u2_nickname,
     max(user_messages.created_at) as created_at'
  )
->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
->groupBy(
    DB::raw(
        'if (user_messages.from_id = '.$user_id.', user_messages.to_id, user_messages.from_id)'
        )
  )
->get()
->toArray();
```